# Algo for bookmark change in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have one javascript  array like `['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','1.2.1',.......]`
It is forming bookmark sequence like :

```
1   
    1.1
        1.1.1
    1.2
        1.2.1
            1.2.1.1
        1.2.2
2
    2.1
        2.1.1
    2.2
    2.3
3   
    3.1
    3.2
    3.3
4
    4.1
```

Now i need to modify the array to start it from 7 like ['7','7.1','7.1.1',7.2......] It has to be changed downwards accordingly like.Previously it was starting from 1 ,after modification it starts from 7.

```
7
    7.1
        7.1.1
    7.2
        7.2.1
            7.2.1.1
        7.2.2
8
    8.1
        8.1.1
    8.2
    8.3
9
    9.1
    9.2
    9.3
10
    10.1
```

Basically it is down the line sequence change . 1 becomes 7 impacting 1.1 to 7.1 .Similarly down the line .
I am novice programer looking for some solution in javascript to modify array list .

Comment: Loop and `6 + parseInt('N.X.Y. ..', 10)` as the parseInt will always be `N` for any integer `N`

Comment: Alex will you please elaborate ..if i do parseInt('N.X.Y','7.1.2') it gives NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and elegant solution:

```
var bookmark = ['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','1.2.1','1.2.1.1','1.2.2','2','2.1','2.1.1','2.2','2.3','3','3.1','3.2','3.3','4','4.1'];

function updateBookmark(bookmark) {
  var split = bookmark.split('.');
  split[0] = 6 + +split[0];
  return split.join('.');
}

var updatedBookmark = bookmark.map(updateBookmark);
```

---

Not part of the question, but if you wanted say to change every 2.x.y to be 2.x.(3+y), you could do so with very few changes:

```
function updateBookmark(bookmark) {
  var split = bookmark.split('.');
  if (split[0] !== '2' || split.length < 3) return bookmark;
  split[2] = 3 + +split[2];
  return split.join('.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about;

```
var x = ['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','1.2.1','2','2.1'];
var y = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var value = x[i];
    var int = parseInt(value, 10) + 6;
    y.push(int + value.substr((value + ".").indexOf(".")));    
}

console.log(y)

>> ["7", "7.1", "7.1.1", "7.2", "7.2.1", "8", "8.1"]
```